# How to cache image (or few images) in browser or in react.js app for instant loading when return to that page?

Tags: reactjs, image, caching

On first rendering on /welcome page image is downloaded. But after that when I go to other page and return again on /welcome image is again downloaded. So, every time I have glitch while image is downloading. I screenshot to see the problem:

[image: multiple download the same image]

And this is how /welcome page looks like while image is in downloading phase:

[image]

How to prevent that multiple downloading every time when user returns to /welcome page and to show image instant?

This is my code for that:

```
import Graphic from '@app/assets/images/undraw_city_life_gnpr.webp';

export const WelcomePage = () => {
  return (
       ....
        <Box justifyContent="center">
          <img
            src={Graphic}
            width="100%"
          />
        </Box>
       ....
  )
}
```